# Java, tomcat8: MYSQL query start to become very low after some hours that the deploy of a new .war has been done

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jooq

I have a java website (a forum, to be more precise) which is hosted from a debian VPS, thanks to tomcat8.

The website was not written by me, it was transfered to my ownership some days ago and I'm starting to write my code.

The DAO (repository) of the application is based on JOOQ, but I don't like it, so I decided to write new queries by simply using the mysql jdbc connector.
At the moment I have written only one new query to get all sections of the forum.

The query works well, but only for a few hours. Some hours after the deploy of the new WAR, the query start to become so slow that it can not be completed. So, I have to restart the web server. After the restart the query works well, but still only for a few hours.

Here below you can see the code of the class MiscDAO, which contains the method "getForums". This is the method which contains the query.
The dataSource (BasicDataSource) is passed to the base class, which keeps the reference as a class member (the same for the jooq variable).

```
public class MiscDAO extends BaseDAO {

    public MiscDAO(DSLContext jooq, BasicDataSource dataSource) {
        super(jooq, dataSource);
    }

    public List<String> getForums() {

        String query = "select forums.id\n" + 
                "from forums\n" + 
                "left join messages on forums.id=messages.forum\n" + 
                "and forums.enabled=1\n" + 
                "group by forums.id\n" + 
                "order by count(forums.id) desc;";

        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet result = null;
        PreparedStatement stat = null;

        try {
            conn = dataSource.getConnection();


            stat = dataSource.getConnection()
                    .prepareStatement(query);


            result = stat.executeQuery();

            List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();

            while(result.next()) {
                res.add(result.getString("id"));
            }

            return res;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            return null;
        }

        finally {
            CloseDbResources(conn, stat, result);
        }           
    }

}
```

Here below the method "CloseDbResources" in the BaseDAO class.

```
protected void CloseDbResources(Connection connection, PreparedStatement preparedStatement, ResultSet resultSet) {
        if (resultSet != null) {
            try {
                resultSet.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) { }
        }
        if (preparedStatement != null) {
            try {
                preparedStatement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) { }
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) { }
        }
    }
```

And finally, the code of the init method in the DAO Factory, where the instance of the class MiscDAO is created. Note that the MiscDAO class is the exclusive one which receives BasicDataSource as paramether, and the reason is that I wanted to start the conversion from jooq to simple sql.

```
void init(Properties databaseConfig) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        String driver = databaseConfig.getProperty("driverclass");
        Class.forName(driver);

        String username = databaseConfig.getProperty("username");
        String password = databaseConfig.getProperty("password");
        String url = databaseConfig.getProperty("url");

        dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setMaxTotal(15);
        dataSource.setMaxIdle(10);
        dataSource.setMinIdle(3);
        dataSource.setMaxWaitMillis(30000);
        dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        dataSource.setTestWhileIdle(true);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
        dataSource.setValidationQueryTimeout(30);



        DSLContext jooq = DSL.using(dataSource, SQLDialect.MYSQL);

        authorsDAO = new AuthorsDAO(jooq);
        threadsDAO = new ThreadsDAO(jooq);
        messagesDAO = new MessagesDAO(jooq);
        pollsDAO = new PollsDAO(jooq);
        quotesDAO = new QuotesDAO(jooq);
        bookmarksDAO = new BookmarksDAO(jooq);
        adminDAO = new AdminDAO(jooq);
        miscDAO = new MiscDAO(jooq, dataSource);
        privateMsgDAO = new PrivateMsgDAO(jooq);
        digestDAO = new DigestDAO(jooq);
        loginsDAO = new LoginsDAO(jooq);
    }
```

The class DAOFactory is a singleton, so the init method is called only once, when the class is istantiated.

```
static synchronized DAOFactory getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            String persistenceName = FdTConfig.getProperty("persistence.name");
            try {
                instance = new DAOFactory();
                instance.init(FdTConfig.getDatabaseConfig(persistenceName));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.fatal("Cannot instantiate Persistence '" + persistenceName + "'", e);
                return null;
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

Here below you can see the old code, the one which was written by the old owner of the website and worked well. The query was based on jooq.
Note that the query used to get the forum sections from the messages table. The reason is that the table "forums" didn't exist. 
It was created by me some days ago, and that's why I wrote the new query.

```
public List<String> getForums() {

        Result<Record1<String>> records = jooq.select(MESSAGES.FORUM)
            .from(MESSAGES)
            .where(MESSAGES.FORUM.isNotNull())
            .groupBy(MESSAGES.FORUM)
            .orderBy(DSL.count(MESSAGES.ID).desc(), MESSAGES.FORUM.asc())
            .fetch();


        List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>(records.size());
        for (Record1<String> record : records) {
            res.add(record.getValue(FORUMS.ID));
        }

        return res;
    }
```

In the DaoFactory the instance of the class MiscDAO used to be created in this way (the exclusive difference is that the class didn't take the BaiscDataSource as paramether, so the BasicDataSource was encapsulated inside jooq and never used directly.

```
miscDAO = new MiscDAO(jooq);
```

Here below you can read the error in the log file, which occurs after some hours that the new war has been deployed.

```
2018-04-01 13:46:50,154 ERROR MainServlet:509 -
         java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException    at
         sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor98.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
         sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
         com.forumdeitroll.servlets.MainServlet.doDo(MainServlet.java:241)  at
         com.forumdeitroll.servlets.MainServlet.doGetPost(MainServlet.java:120)
            at com.forumdeitroll.servlets.MainServlet.doGet(MainServlet.java:110)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)     at
         javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)   at
         org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
            at
         org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            at
         org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
            at
         org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
            at
         org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            at com.forumdeitroll.filters.MainFilter.doFilter(MainFilter.java:86)
            at
         org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
            at
         org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            at
         org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
            at
         org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
            at
         org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
            at
         org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
            at
         org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
            at
         org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
            at
         org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
            at
         org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
            at
         org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
            at
         org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
            at
         org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
            at
         org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1580)
            at
         org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1537)
            at
         java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at
         java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at
         org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
         org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: Error getting connection from
         data source org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource@41b7afc6  at
         org.jooq.impl.DataSourceConnectionProvider.acquire(DataSourceConnectionProvider.java:89)
            at
         org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.connection(DefaultExecuteContext.java:583)
            at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:311)  at
         org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchLazy(AbstractResultQuery.java:319)
            at
         org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchLazy(AbstractResultQuery.java:306)
            at
         org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchAny(AbstractResultQuery.java:523)
            at org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.fetchAny(SelectImpl.java:2512)  at
         com.forumdeitroll.persistence.dao.BaseDAO.getAuthor(BaseDAO.java:51)
            at
         com.forumdeitroll.persistence.dao.MessagesDAO.recordToDTO(MessagesDAO.java:289)
            at
         com.forumdeitroll.persistence.dao.MessagesDAO.getMessages(MessagesDAO.java:110)
            at com.forumdeitroll.servlets.Messages.getMessages(Messages.java:781)
            at com.forumdeitroll.servlets.Messages.getMessages(Messages.java:87)
            ... 33 more Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a
         connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object     at
         org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:142)
            at
         org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1533)
            at
         org.jooq.impl.DataSourceConnectionProvider.acquire(DataSourceConnectionProvider.java:86)
            ... 44 more Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Timeout
         waiting for idle object    at
         org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:449)
            at
         org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
            at
         org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:134)
            ... 46 more
```

Comment: 'I don't like it' is not a sufficient reason to introduce new bugs into working code. You appear to be initialozonf multiple pools here, as `init()` is not static.

Comment: @EJP  the class DAOFactory is a singleton, so the init method is called only once.
I've just updated the OP, so you can read how the class DAOFactory is istantiated.

Answer (score 0):

It's really a difficult thing to detect. I am not 100% sure about the exact reason but below are some of the tips that you should consider:-

1. Max no of connections are not sufficient. Hence, try increasing the number of max connections to 50.
2. `Connection` might not be getting closed properly.  Things look good from code perspective but still, I would recommend using `try with resource` as it internally makes sure to close the connection.

   ```
   try(conn = dataSource.getConnection();
       stat = dataSource.getConnection()
               .prepareStatement(query);
       result = stat.executeQuery();) {
       List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();

       while(result.next()) {
           res.add(result.getString("id"));
       }
       return res;
   } catch (SQLException e) {
       return null;
   }
   ```
3. Make sure that whenever you deploy a new war you actually shut down the tomcat completely. As there might be the case that your code never got a chance to release the connection it acquired due to tomcat activities.
4. Try to find out how many concurrent users are trying to access the application. If these significantly exceed the max no of connections. You need to increase the maximum no. of connections allowed.

I am exploring further to find out more possible reasons around same.

Comment: What do you mean with "shut dow down tomcat completely"? I use "sudo service tomcat8 stop".

Note that I'm using th class BasicDataSource... I don't know if it's the correct class for what I have to do.

I don't think the problem is the max number of connections, because there are only a few users in the forum. 
However, can you suggest a debian/tomcat command to see all connections to the web server in real time?